# No result with port forwading with mono.nat

Tags: c#-4.0, mono, portforwarding

Hi guys any one can help me with mono.nat dll , i do what this url said but nothing happens , upnp is activated in my router but i get no result.
url : http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/upnp-port-forwarding-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you NAT is an ADSL modem instead of an IP router. Try [Open.NAT](https://github.com/lontivero/Open.Nat) and please read it [documentacion](https://github.com/lontivero/Open.Nat/wiki).

I hope it can help you. If it doesn't work (doen't worry, it will) enable the tracing with verbose level and open an issue in github.

Comment: Those reading, Open.NAT has not been updated since 2017. Its recommended to find a alternative maintained library, like Mono.NAT (which is actively maintained).